# setOnItemClickListener in a fragment and image view

Tags: android

When I want to use `setOnItemClickListener` I use the below

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(Tab1Fragment.getContext(null)));
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Send intent to SingleViewActivity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleViewActivity.class);
           // Pass image index
           i.putExtra("id", position);
           startActivity(i);
    } 
});
```

But for the below code I am not able to do like the above :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview1, null);
    GridView listView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainGrid1);
    listView.setAdapter(new Adapter());
    GridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {         
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Send intent to SingleViewActivity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleViewActivity.class);
            // Pass image index
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

[image]
this is an error image

Comment: Instead of `GridView.setOnItemClickListener`, do `listView.setOnItemClickListener()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are using Class name Gridview instead of gridview variable you have declared as listview

wrong code:-

```
GridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {         
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    // Send intent to SingleViewActivity
               Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleViewActivity.class);
               // Pass image index
               i.putExtra("id", position);
               startActivity(i);
               } });
```

Instead of above code change it to

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {         
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    // Send intent to SingleViewActivity
               Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleViewActivity.class);
               // Pass image index
               i.putExtra("id", position);
               startActivity(i);
               } });
```

Comment: Dnt know why the downvote anyway ill check ur advice

Comment: but i am having error on getapplicationContext is undefined for the type new adapteeview.onitemclicklistener

Comment: use getActivity() instead of getapplicationContext as you are using fragment

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
GridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {  
    ....              
} });
```

Do this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {  
    ....              
} });
```

GridView is a class while listView is a GridView variable which you have initialized in your code. Use that instead.

Comment: but i am having error on getapplicationContext is undefined for the type new adapteeview.onitemclicklistener

Comment: Instead of getApplicationContext(), use getActivity() instead, since you're inside a Fragment.